# Laravel application architecture

Tags: laravel, eloquent

*I am using laravel.*

Lets say there are two tables A and B (A and B are interrelated;their relation is defined in models) of which controllers and models are as follows

- ControllerA
- ControllerB
- ModelA
- ModelB

I want to save data in table A and B. Before saving data, there is need of data validation and check whether that is accessible to particular user or not.
I have following functions

- SaveA
- SaveB
- ValidationA
- ValidationB
- AuthenticationUserA
- AuthenticationUserB

I am calling an API that points to saveA function of ControllerA. I am unable to understand where saveB, autheticationUserB and validationB should be kept(Although I want to save data in table B).

Comment: Since their relationship is defined in the model, you can likely use Laravel's save method on the relationship as well. See [Inserting Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models)

Comment: What about validationB and AuthenticationUserB @camelCase

Comment: You can validate in the controller that calls the relationship's save method.

Comment: I need to write(validation and authorization) twice, in both the controller.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using Requests (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests) - Assuming your using Laravel 5.1.

Run

`php artisan make:request YourRequestName`

Then in your controller (api end point) use the request e.g

```
public function myEndpoint(MyRequestName $request)
{
   do something. 
}
```

in your request you would define your permissions requirement and validation rules.

Comment: could you elaborate this little bit more @tonycodes